# The overflow of angular ng-select in a table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-ngselect

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg" style="overflow-y: auto;">
            <table class="mt-3 table-borderless table-striped table singleTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Item Name</th>
               </thead>
               <tbody class="tableBody">
                   <tr>
                       <td scope="col">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <ng-select id="ngSelectState" class="mat-outline custom" 
                              [multiple]="false" [items]="itemList"
                              bindLabel="Value" bindValue="Text" [(ngModel)]="item.ItemId" 
                              floatingLabel appendTo=".form-group" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: 
                                true}">
                              </ng-select>
                              <label class="mat-outline-label required" for="mySelect" 
                               [class.active]="item.ItemId">Item Name</label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

[image: The ng-select list should be above the table, basically it goes inside the table and make the overflow in the table, how can I fix it]

The ng-select list should be above the table, basically it goes inside the table and make the overflow in the table, how can I fix it